Matlab cellfun, how to apply indexing to strings on each element?
I'm having trouble indexing into strings contained in a cell array using the cellfun function.  I have a cell array with strings of various contents, and I'm trying to extract the numbers between the words "input" and "dBm" in the following example, where the lines of interest always have the word "atten". (My actual usage has dozens of lines, but this is a simplified example).  I'm able to get the indices for the cells that contain "atten" using the "contains" function, which works as expected.  I am also able to get the indices in each cell that I want to extract using the "strfind" function inside cellfun, which are showed as variables "st" and "sp" below.
But I'm unable to use the "st" and "sp" values to extract the numbers of interest, which are -70.6, -67.5, and -69.9 in this example.  Is this type of indexing possible using cellfun?  Or should I just go with a for loop?
The commented code at the bottom shows the values I'm getting in out_cell_array currently, and what I what to obtain.
d = {'some random text';...
    'atten 16.0 input -70.6 dBm';...
    'atten 0.0 input -67.5 dBm';...
    'atten 13.0 input -69.9 dBm';...
    'some other random text'};

idx = find(contains(d,'atten'));
st = cellfun(@(x) strfind(x, 'input'), d(idx)) + 6;     % index starting 6 to the right "input"
sp = cellfun(@(x) strfind(x, 'dBm'), d(idx)) - 2;       % index starting 2 to the left of "dBm"     
out_cell_array = cellfun(@(x){x(st:sp)}, d(idx));

%values after running above. everything works until the last "cellfun" line, which isn't indexing how I want
% disp(idx')            2 3 4
% disp(d(idx)')         'atten 16.0 input -70.6 dBm'  'atten 0.0 input -67.5 dBm'  'atten 16.0 input -69.9 dBm'
% disp(st')             18 17 18
% disp(sp')             22 21 22
% disp(out_cell_array') '-70.6' '67.5 ' '-69.9'  <-- is not indexing using the values of st and sp

%%%% I want this:
% out_cell_array = {d{2}(18:22); d{3}(17:21); d{4}(18:22)};
% disp(out_cell_array')  '-70.6' '-67.5' '-69.9'


You should always write a plain loop first, unless the vectorization is trivial and obvious. If it then turns out to be too slow (a bottleneck in your code), then you can start thinking about putting in the effort to vectorize. In modern versions of MATLAB, vectorized code is often not significantly faster than loop code, and sometimes much slower (when it needs very large intermediate arrays), so it often is not worth putting in the effort to vectorize.

Okay, that's fine.  I will go with a for loop.  Thanks.

The x, st, and sp in your last cellfun don't match up. Try this:
x = d(idx); % extract the appropriate cells first
arrayfun(@(k)x{k}(st(k):sp(k)),(1:numel(st))','uni',false') % then extract the strings

Or, if you really want to use cellfun,
cellfun(@(x,st,sp){x(st:sp)}, d(idx),num2cell(st),num2cell(sp))


Thank you.  I couldn't use the other suggestion with "matches" because I use an older version of Matlab, so this is my winner :)

You can use the string functions matches together with some patterns, as well as extractBetween to make this pretty simple:
% Find all elements that start with "atten", and have "input" and "dBm"
ismatch = matches(d, "atten" + wildcardPattern + "input" + wildcardPattern + "dBm");
% Pick out whatever is between "input" and "dBm" and convert it to double.
str2double(extractBetween(d(ismatch), "input", "dBm"))


Thanks.  I could use the matches function because my version of Matlab uses some Java method.  But I will keep this in mind if my company ever upgrades our license :)            >> which matches
matches is a Java method  % java.lang.String method

That's a shame. I think the text-processing capabilites in recent versions of MATLAB make life much simpler.
